# How to free recursive struct (trie)

Tags: c, recursion, struct, free, trie

**FINAL EDIT**

My function that frees the memory works properly, and as milevyo has suggested, the problem lies in node creation, which I had fixed. I now have a separate problem where the program segfaults when run normally, but it cannot be reproduced in `gdb` or `valgrind`. However, that is a separate question altogether.

I have since found out that this segfault happened because I did not check for the EOF character properly. [As per Cliff B's answer in this question](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/15353/pset5-load-function-segfault-do-not-show-in-gdb), the check for EOF happens only after the last character in the file. As a result, in my function that loads the dictionary file, I had assigned the last character of the file to some `i` (which in this case was -1 according to a `printf` call), and tried to create and access a child node if index -1. This caused a segmentation fault, and also caused problems with my unload function, which would not unload the very last node I created.

As to why the segmentation fault does not appear when I run the program in `gdb` or `valgrind`, I have no idea.

**EDIT 3**

While stepping through my load function where the node creation happens, I notice an unexpected behaviour. I believe the problem lies somewhere in these lines of code, which are embedded within a `for` loop. The casting to `(node*)` is just to be safe, though it does not affect the running of the code to my knowledge.

```
// if node doesnt exist, calloc one, go to node
if (current_node->children[i] == NULL)
{
    current_node->children[i] = (node*) calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    nodes++;
}
current_node = current_node->children[i];
```

While stepping through the load function, I see that my `current_node->children[i]` seem to be `calloc`'ed properly (all children set to `NULL`), but the moment I step into `current_node->children[i]` and examine its children (see image below), I see that the addresses get screwed up. Specifically, the `i`'th child in the children node gets set to `0x0` for some reason. While `0x0` is supposed to be equal to `NULL` (correct me if I'm wrong), my `free_all` function seems to want to go into the `0x0` pointer, which of course results in a segfault.  Can anyone shed light on how this might happen?

[Values of children[i]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j7sG.png)

**EDIT 2**: I'm using `calloc` to create my nodes

`root = calloc(1, sizeof(node));`

For my child nodes, they are created within a for loop where I iterate over characters of the dictionary file I'm reading in.

```
if (current_node->children[i] == NULL)
{
    current_node->children[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    nodes++;
}
```

`c` in this case represents the character of the word being read in. I get `i` using the following:

```
if (c == '\'')
    i = 26;
else if (isalpha(c))
    i = c - 97;
```

**EDIT**: I'm thinking that something in my node creation is faulty, as milevyo suggested. This is because if I print out the addresses, it goes from `0x603250` to `0x603340` to `0x603430` to `0x603520`, then finally to `(nil)`, before it segfaults. I have verified that the root node gets passed in correctly by printing out its value in gdb. I'll try to figure it out.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm running into a segfault when trying to free a recursive struct, but cannot figure out why, and would like some help.

My struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
}
node;
```

This is meant to implement a trie structure in which to load a dictionary into, for purposes of a spellcheck. After the spellcheck is done, I need to free the memory that I've allocated to the trie.

This is my current function which should free the trie when passed the root node, but it segfaults when doing so, though not immediately:

```
void free_all(node* curs)
{
    int i;

    // recursive case (go to end of trie)
    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (curs->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            free_all(curs->children[i]);
        }
    }

    // base case
    free(curs);
}
```

Where could I have gone wrong? If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: @bolov Yes ,read that . Therefore , removed comment :)

Comment: The posted code looks OK. The problem lies in other parts of your code.

Comment: Show us how you are creating a `trie`.

Comment: Are you initializing the entries in `children` to NULL when you first allocate a `node`?  If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: i can not see the purpose of using NODES here, thus i think the problem is in the logic you are using. (NODES do not store any useful value)

Comment: @milevyo: the nodes here are only useful for their `bool` value `is_word`. I will load a dictionary into the `trie`, with each node's `is_word` value signifying that the word exists. This is then used in a word checker program which passes words into the `trie`, and checks if the word exists in the trie. If it does not, the word is misspelled.

Comment: still i can not get the picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think, root node is faulty ( maybe it is null). if not, look elsewhere. in node creation for example.

```
void free_all(node* curs)
{
    int i;
    if(!curs) return;   // safe guard including root node. 

    // recursive case (go to end of trie)
    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++)
       free_all(curs->children[i]);


    // base case
    free(curs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `free_all` function is ok. You have to check you set to `NULL` all children not allocated. This includes nodes that are not leaves, but don't have all the `27` children.

If that is ok, or fixing it doesn't fix the segfault, you have to debug.

Comment: I allocated memory to my nodes using `calloc` and not `malloc`, and to my knowledge that already sets all children to `NULL`, so that should not be the problem

Comment: @panzer. Yes, `calloc` should set them to `NULL`. If you are paranoid, you cold just double check (I would). As I've said, the best option now is to debug. Good luck :)